# A "What am I?" puzzle

Tags: riddle

I am made up of 66 parts, some old and some new.
I start at the beginning, and finish at the end.
I have songs in the middle, next to some wise old sayings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you are

> the Protestant Bible

I am made up of 66 parts, some old and some new.

> 66 books in the Protestant bible, broken up into the old and new testaments

I start at the beginning, and finish at the end.

> Start with Genesis, the beginning of the world.  End with Revelation, the end of the world

I have songs in the middle, next to some wise old sayings.

> Psalms, Book of Songs, and Proverbs

Comment: seems like i'm 3 minutes too slow, although it did take a lot of googling from my end...

Comment: @fysh I might award you a $50$ rep bounty, since your answer is exactly the same as this one, even though it did not get accepted :)

Comment: @user477343 this answer was the first, and technically point 3 of this answer is correct, whereas fysh did not get it quite right.

Comment: @JamieBarker **fysh** did not *quite* get it right; his/her answer was slightly different than **SteveV**'s answer but it is very very close, regardless of Point 3. In my honest opinion, we can say that it is pretty much the same, so close to being exact that the difference does not really need to be considered, but again, that is just my thoughts :P

Answer (score 4):

You are

> the Bible

I am made up of 66 parts, some old and some new.

> 39 Old Testament and 27 New Testament books make up 66

I start at the beginning, and finish at the end.

> The Bible starts with the creation of the universe and finishes with the end of the curse of sin.

I have songs in the middle, next to some wise old sayings.

> The Bible contains an abundance of songs (there's even a Song of Songs!) as well as phrases that have been inculcated into daily use.